# How to remove duplication?

Tags: java, design-patterns

```
//Represents list books command for biblioteca

public class ListBooksCommand implements Command {

    private static final String BOOKS = "Books::";
    private static final String FORMAT = "%-35s %-35s %-35s";
    private static final String HEADER = String.format(FORMAT, "Name", "Author", "YearPublished");
    private static final String NO_BOOKS_AVAILABLE = "No Books Available";

    private final Biblioteca biblioteca;
    private final IO io;

    public ListBooksCommand(Biblioteca biblioteca, IO io) {
        this.biblioteca = biblioteca;
        this.io = io;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        if (this.biblioteca.isEmpty(Book.class)) {
            this.io.println(NO_BOOKS_AVAILABLE);
            return;
        }
        this.displayBooks();
    }

    private void displayBooks() {
        this.io.println(BOOKS);
        this.io.println(HEADER);
        this.io.println(this.biblioteca.representationOfAllLibraryItems(Book.class));
    }

}    

public class ListMoviesCommand implements Command {

    private static final String Movies = "Movies::";
    private static final String FORMAT = "%-35s %-35s %-35s";
    private static final String HEADER = String.format(FORMAT, "Name", "Director", "YearPublished");
    private static final String NO_BOOKS_AVAILABLE = "No Movies Available";

    private final Biblioteca biblioteca;
    private final IO io;

    public ListBooksCommand(Biblioteca biblioteca, IO io) {
        this.biblioteca = biblioteca;
        this.io = io;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        if (this.biblioteca.isEmpty(Movie.class)) {
            this.io.println(NO_MOVIES_AVAILABLE);
            return;
        }
        this.displayMovies();
    }

    private void displayMovies() {
        this.io.println(MOVIES);
        this.io.println(HEADER);
        this.io.println(this.biblioteca.representationOfAllLibraryItems(MOVIE.class));
    }

}
```

I have two classes here one is listbooks command , listmovies command both acts on biblioteca. Both Book and Movie is of type LibraryItem(interface).
Both below codes are same. Both will ask biblioteca to get the representation of its own type. And both commands will display the representation.

This is biblioteca implementation

```
//Represents a library

public class Biblioteca {

    private final List<LibraryItem> allLibraryItems;

        public String representationOfAllLibraryItems(Class<? extends LibraryItem> itemType) {
    return this.allLibraryItems
            .stream()
            .filter(libraryItem -> libraryItem.getClass().equals(itemType))
            .map(LibraryItem::representation)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(LINE_SEPARATOR));
}

public boolean isEmpty(Class<? extends LibraryItem> itemType) {
    return this.allLibraryItems.stream().noneMatch(libraryItem -> libraryItem.getClass().equals(itemType));
}

}
```

Please suggest me a pattern to avoid duplication.

Comment: It seems wrong that these types `implements Command`. They should implement/extend a parent type that handles this sort of bookeping (e.g. a `LibraryItem` abstract class - you've alluded to such a type already existing). The abstract class should handle asking the `Biblioteca` if any such items exist, so that the subclasses can be concerned only with how they're displayed.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. You are saying, both below code are similar. Which code are you talking about?

Comment: Both listbooksCommand, ListMoviesCommand have same code right.

Comment: Now check code once

Comment: What I feel is your design is falling short at a point where you are defining `Biblioteca` and implementing `Command`. Before proceeding further, ask yourself whether `ListBooks` and `ListMovies` **are** `Biblioteca`.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** I'm not aware about your requirements. I'm just proposing some general design observations in this answer.

**Observation 1:** `Biblioteca` being a library, **has** library items. In your case, the items in the library are `Movie` items and `Book` items. So the library **has** two main types of items (or it can even contain more. Doesn't matter). Hence the member of `Biblioteca` should be:

```
private HashMap<Class<? extends LibraryItem>, List<LibraryItem>> libraryItems;
```

A map that has item type as `Key` and `List<LibraryItem>` as value.
`Biblioteca` should also contain querying methods that will return the representations for a given **item type** and representations for **all item types**. So in my view, `Biblioteca` class should look like this:

```
public class Biblioteca {
    private HashMap<Class<? extends LibraryItem>, List<LibraryItem>> libraryItems;

    public Biblioteca(HashMap<Class<? extends LibraryItem>, List<LibraryItem>> libraryItems) {
        this.libraryItems = libraryItems;
    }

    /*
     * Representation of a given type
     */
    public String representationOfLibraryItemType(Class<? extends LibraryItem> itemType) {
        if(libraryItems.containsKey(itemType)) {
            return libraryItems.get(itemType).stream()
                                        .filter(libraryItem -> libraryItem.getClass().equals(itemType))
                                        .map(LibraryItem::representation)
                                        .collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Missing type " + itemType.getSimpleName());
        }
    }

    /*
     * Representation of all types
     */
    public List<String> representationOfAllLibraryItems() {

        return libraryItems.values()
                           .stream()
                           .flatMap(list -> list.stream()
                                                .map(LibraryItem::representation))
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

The method `representationOfLibraryItemType` should be taking in a `Class` of **item type** for filtering. If the item type is found in the library, return it's representations or else throw an exception saying it's an unknown item type.

On the other hand, `representationOfAllLibraryItems()` should not take any input parameters. It should return all the available representations in the library.

**Observation 2:** Your `LibraryItem` should be an abstract class and each of the items in your library should extend this particular class. Because `Movie` **is-a** `LibraryItem` and `Book` **is-a** `LibraryItem`. Now, each of your items can override `representation()` method which is an **abstract method** in `LibraryItem`. Your `LibraryItem` class should look something like this:

```
public abstract class LibraryItem {
    abstract String representation();
}
```

**Observation 3:** Your `Book` and `Movie` classes should be independent of `Biblioteca` because they are just items **in-a** Library. Today they are in a library called `Biblioteca` and tomorrow they can be in a library called `CentralHallLibrary`. So, your item class should be looking something like this:

```
/*
 * Book Item
 */ 
public class Book extends LibraryItem {

    private String title;
    private String author;
    private String publishedYear;


    public Book(String title, String author, String publishedYear) {
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.publishedYear = publishedYear;
    }

    @Override
    public String representation() {
        /*
         * I'm just returning a call to toString
         * from this method. You can replace it
         * with your representation logic.
         */
        return toString();

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Book [title=" + title + ", author=" + author + ", publishedYear=" + publishedYear + "]";
    }

}

/*
 * Movie Item
 */
public class Movie extends LibraryItem {
    private String title;
    private String director;
    private String releaseYear;


    public Movie(String title, String director, String releaseYear) {
        this.title = title;
        this.director = director;
        this.releaseYear = releaseYear;
    }



    @Override
    public String representation() {
        /*
         * I'm just returning a call to toString
         * from this method. You can replace it
         * with your representation logic.
         */
        return toString();

    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Movie [title=" + title + ", director=" + director + ", releaseYear=" + releaseYear + "]";
    }

}
```

**Observation 4:** I didn't find any use of the `Command` class which you are using. Because, as I see, your `Command` class has only one method called `execute()` that is used for displaying the representations. Generally I would put such "displaying" code in my client side (UI). If `Command` class has no other functions other than only printing stuff, it's not necessary in my opinion.

**Testing the design:** Let's create few `Book` items and few `Movie` items and then add those to the `Biblioteca` library

```
        Book effJava = new Book("Effective Java", "Josh Bloch", "2008");
        Book cloudNativeJava = new Book("Cloud Native Java", "Josh Long", "2017");
        Book java9modularity = new Book("Java 9 Modularity", "Paul Bakker", "2017");

        Movie gotgV2 = new Movie("Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2", "James Gunn", "2017");
        Movie wonderWoman = new Movie("Wonder Woman", "Patty Jenkins", "2017");
        Movie spiderHomeCmg = new Movie("Spider-man Homecoming", "Jon Watts", "2017");

        List<LibraryItem> bookItems = new ArrayList<>();
        List<LibraryItem> movieItems = new ArrayList<>();

        bookItems.add(java9modularity);
        movieItems.add(spiderHomeCmg);
        bookItems.add(cloudNativeJava);
        movieItems.add(wonderWoman);
        bookItems.add(effJava);
        movieItems.add(gotgV2);

        HashMap<Class<? extends LibraryItem>, List<LibraryItem>> store = new HashMap<>();
        store.put(Movie.class, movieItems);
        store.put(Book.class, bookItems);

        //CREATE STORE
        Biblioteca bibloiteca = new Biblioteca(store);
```

Now, on querying the library for all representations -

```
List<String> allLibraryItemsRep = bibloiteca.representationOfAllLibraryItems();
```

Will return a result having both `Movie` and `Book` representations.

On querying the library for specific item types -

```
String movieRep = bibloiteca.representationOfLibraryItemType(Movie.class);
String bookRep = bibloiteca.representationOfLibraryItemType(Book.class);
```

Will return specific representations -

```
Movie [title=Spider-man Homecoming, director=Jon Watts, releaseYear=2017]
Movie [title=Wonder Woman, director=Patty Jenkins, releaseYear=2017]
Movie [title=Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2, director=James Gunn, releaseYear=2017]

Book [title=Java 9 Modularity, author=Paul Bakker, publishedYear=2017]
Book [title=Cloud Native Java, author=Josh Long, publishedYear=2017]
Book [title=Effective Java, author=Josh Bloch, publishedYear=2008]
```

On querying the library for the type which is not present in the library -

```
String carRep = bibloiteca.representationOfLibraryItemType(Car.class);
```

Will throw an exception -

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing type Car
```

I understand that this is quite a lengthy answer and hope this brought some clarity about the design.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a generic class `ListItemsCommand` which will accept the item name or class as a parameter for listing and checking for empty list. 
And then call `ListItemsCommand` with the item type like `Movie` or `Book`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove duplication I suggest using a collect with `groupingBy`. This allows you to specify which is the key used for deduplication (or grouping) and a reduction function which in case of a duplicate selects the element which is to be selected from the set of duplicates.

Here is a sample method with the `groupingBy` collector:

```
public String representationOfAllLibraryItems(Class<? extends LibraryItem> itemType) {
    return this.allLibraryItems
            .stream()
            .filter(libraryItem -> libraryItem.getClass().equals(itemType))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(LibraryItem::getName, LinkedHashMap::new,
                    Collectors.reducing((o1, o2) -> o1.toString().compareTo(o2.toString()) < 0 ? o1 : o2)))
            .values()
            .stream()
            .map(Optional::get)
            .map(LibraryItem::representation)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(LINE_SEPARATOR));
}
```

Here is a small test in which we de-duplicate by name of the movie and select the most recent entry in the data:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<LibraryItem> items = Arrays.asList(new Movie("Valerian", "Luc Besson", "2017"),
            new Movie("Valerian", "Luc Besson", "2016"),
            new Movie("Spiderman", "Sam Raimi", "2002"),
            new Movie("Spiderman", "Sam Raimi", "2001"),
            new Movie("Spiderman", "Sam Raimi", "2003"));
    Biblioteca biblioteca = new Biblioteca(items);
    System.out.println(biblioteca.representationOfAllLibraryItems(Movie.class));
}
```

The result looks like this:

```
Luc Besson - Valerian - 2017
Sam Raimi - Spiderman - 2003
```

Here the de-duplication happens by movie name and the most recent movie is selected.